# Steam app and age verification issue

Tags: macos, steam

I have OSX 10.9.4 with the Steam App (API v016 and package versions 1407966480) installed. When I would visit game pages that required age verification, my birthday would be filled in due to being logged in and I would just click OK to move past.

Now the age verification shows up with January 1st, 2014 each time and it will not let me change the date. The drop down menus just show up blank.

[image]

I have tried to log out of my computer, log out of Steam, restart Steam, restart my computer, and reinstall Steam. Nothing has worked and it continues to have this issue. When I visit the Steam website, the age verification drop downs work just fine.

What is causing this issue? And/or how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sign up for the [Steam Beta](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/SteamClientBeta) and try the latest beta client.

Comment: This sounds like a rendering issue.  Since its likely a bug within the application itself I suggest reporting the problem to Steam.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. You're not the only one!!

Comment: @EthanWelborn Here is the link to the Steam Support question I posted. The posted answer did not work for me. https://support.steampowered.com/view.php?ticketref=1901-OGLV-7932

Comment: There was a recent update that corrected the issue (for me at least). Try restarting the Steam Client and trying again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Report the issue to Steam
2. Visit http://store.steampowered.com/ in your browser. Is it broken their too?
3. Not broken? Excellent, enter your age, check out the game, and log in if you want to buy it
4. You can purchase the game on the web, launch your Steam client, and install the game on your computer
5. If website is broken as well then report that to Steam too.

There are certain things you can simply "Add to Cart" like the example below, so if that's available then try it:

[image]